# Variance of a random variable $X$ as a function of the survival function $S(x)$

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival

> Suppose $X$ is a nonnegative and continuous random variable with a
>   survival function $S(x)$.  Show that
>
> $$\mathsf{Var}(X)=2\int_0^\infty tS(t) \, dt-\left( \int_0^\infty S(t) \, dt\right)^2$$

Using the fact that

$$f(x) =−\frac{dS(x)}{dx}$$

we have that

$$\begin{align*}
\mathsf{Var}(X)
&=\mathsf{E}(X^2)-\mathsf{E}(X)^2\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty t^2 f(t)\,dt-\left(\int_0^ \infty tf(t) \, dt \right)^2 \\\\
&=-\int_0^\infty t^2 \, dS(t)-\left(\int_0^\infty t \, dS(t) \right)^2 \\\\
&=-\left(t^2 S(t)\bigg\rvert_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty 2tS(t) \, dt \right) - \left(tS(t)\bigg\rvert_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty S(t) \, dt \right)^2
\end{align*}$$

I could get the desired result by showing

$$t^2 S(t) \bigg\rvert_0^\infty = tS(t) \bigg\rvert_0^\infty = 0 $$

but how do we know if $t$ and $t^2$ go to $\infty$ slower than $S(t)$?

Comment: It may be worth considering the finiteness of the variance in the case of a distibution where $S(t)$ goes to 0 slowly enough that the integrals you look at don't have a finite value (you may want to write improper integrals out as a limit). You may need to make some assumptions about $S$ sufficient to guarantee it has a variance (otherwise the whole exercise is kind of moot), and then see whether under those assumptions the integral converges..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt to prove this using integration-by-parts is the wrong approach, and that is what is leading you to require unnecessary conditions.  The simpler approach is to express the moments using double-integration, and then use [interchange of integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_integration_(calculus)) to get the survival function.  For any non-negative continuous random variable $X$ you can use the interchange of integrals to write the $k$th raw moment as:

$$\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}
\mathbb{E}(X^k) 
= \int \limits_0^\infty t^k f(t) \ dt
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \Bigg[ r^k f(t) \Bigg]_{r=0}^{r=t} \ dt \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_0^\infty \int \limits_0^t k r^{k-1} f(t) \ dr \ dt \\[6pt]
&= k \int \limits_0^\infty r^{k-1} \int \limits_r^\infty f(t) \ dt \ dr \\[6pt]
&= k \int \limits_0^\infty r^{k-1} S(r) \ dr. \\[6pt]
\end{aligned} \end{equation}$$

Substitution of this general result will give you the required expressions for the first and second moments, which then gives you the desired variance expression.